# Make FloatingWindow modal

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, window, avalondock

I am using the `AvalonDock` control to show my views as tabs. In some cases I want to open a new window instead. At the moment, I'm handling that in the **LayoutInitializer**:

```
public void AfterInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument anchorableShown)
{
    if (anchorableShown.Content != null && anchorableShown.Content is ViewModelBase)
    {
        var viewModel = ((ViewModelBase)anchorableShown.Content);
        if (viewModel.Type == ViewModelBase.ViewType.Popup)
        {
            anchorableShown.FloatingWidth = viewModel.PopupWidth;
            anchorableShown.FloatingHeight = viewModel.PopupHeight;
            anchorableShown.FloatingTop = viewModel.PopupTop;
            anchorableShown.FloatingLeft = viewModel.PopupLeft;

            anchorableShown.Float();
        }
    }        
}
```

That works fine. But I want to have this new floated window as a modal window. And it must not be dockable. I don't know where I can handle that.

Comment: floting model window which is not dockable = you don't need AvalonDock for that, just use a standard Window?

Comment: Why do you want exactly a floating window to be modal? What's wrong with "standard" windows?

Comment: @stijn - i want to use the same templates + logic. if i would use "normal" (standard) windows, then i have to implement the same for the windows.

Comment: @dymanoid - i want to use modal windows because the user has to input values for this form - and nothing else. otherwise the user will open another form etc. and my "workflow" will not be correct ...

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think a modal window requires ShowDialog (or a similar principle) so you do need a seperate Window. You can of course host whatever content in that, including AvalonDock so you can reuse code for it, but it won't be an AvalonDock floating window. So unless AvalonDock does have a way of making one of it's windows modal you'll have to go with a seperate Window.

Answer (score 2):

The best way - as @stijn already answered - is to create a seperate window.

Here is my XAML definition:

```
<Window ... >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:FirstViewModel}">
            <local:FirstView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondViewModel}">
            <local:SecondView />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Name="mainPanel" >
        <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding}">
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Foreach ViewModel/View assignment I use this `DataTemplate` block.

In my `WindowManager` implementation, I create a new window:

```
private System.Windows.Window CreateWindow(ViewModelBase viewModel)
{
    var window = new PopupWindow();
    window.DataContext = viewModel;

    return window;
}
```

... and show it as modal window:

```
public void ShowWindow(ViewModelBase viewModel)
{
    var window = CreateWindow(viewModel);
    window.ShowDialog();
}
```